# How to skip specific indexes in an array?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of the form `L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]` and I want to remove the third index where 1 occurs and replace it with 0. My code is this, but this removes the previous indexes of 1(1st and 2nd also) which I want in my List. My code is this

```
counter=0
index = 2
L = list([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4])
print("Value before is\n", L)
for i in range(len(L)):
    y=L.index(1)
    print(y)
    if(counter==index):
        L[y]=0
        break
    else:
        counter=counter+1
        L[y]
        print("Value of list in else\n",L)
        print("Value of counter\n",counter)

print("After the value is\n",L)
```

So output comes as

```
 [2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

but I want it as

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

and remember that I will not be given directly the index which I want to change
So I could Do `L[7]=0`
Thanks in advance

Comment: While your code is still wrong, the output you announced does not match the actual output, can you fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your algorithm, but it boils down to this: by doing `y = L.index(1)` you find the first index where a `1` appears. So by doing `L[y] = 0`, all you can do is update the first occurence of a `1`.

## Finding the nth index

There is no builin to find the *nth* appearance and so you will have to write it.

To be consistent with `list.index`, I made the following `index` function raise a `ValueError` when the item is not found.

#### Code

```
def index(lst, obj, n=1):
    count = 0
    for index, item in enumerate(lst):
        if item == obj:
            count += 1
        if count == n:
            return index
    raise ValueError('{} is not in list at least {} times'.format(obj, n))

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]

index = index(L, 1, n=3)

L[index] = 0

print(L)
```

#### Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

## Using list-comprehension

Alternatively, if all you want to do is replace the *nth* occurence, but do not care about its actual index, you can generate a new list with a list-comprehension and an `itertools.count` object.

#### Code

```
from itertools import count

def replace(lst, obj, repl, n=1):
    counter = count(1)
    return [repl if x == obj and next(counter) == n else x for x in lst]


L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]

new_list = replace(L, 1, 0, n=3)
print(new_list)
```

#### Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

Comment: @ShivamSharma It looks like you tried to ask a question via editing my answer. If you want clarifications, please ask so in comments.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Although, in the question you asked in the edit, you replace count(1) by count(obj). This makes the counter start at obj. You *always* want it to start at 1.

Answer (score 3):

Using `enumerate`

**Demo:**

```
index = 2
value = 1
c = 0
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]

for i, v in enumerate(L):
    if v == value:
        if c == index:
            L[i] = 0
            break
        else:
            c+=1
print( L )
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a counter variable called `timesOccured` for the amount of times the integer `1` occurs in the list.

Once `timesOccured == 3 and L[i] == 1` then you can swap the value of `L[i]` for `0` like so:

```
if timesOccured == 3 and L[i] == 1:
    L[i] = 0
```

I would also suggest getting rid of the `counter` variable unless it is necessary for another portion of your program. The `range` function in `for i in range(L)` returns a list which contains all the indices of `L`. In this case, `range(L)` would return `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. The `for` loop would then iterate through this list, assigning the current value stored in the index of the current iteration in `i`.